# Failed to find newest available simulator runtime - Image.xcassets when building RN app on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am trying to make some adjustments to an app that I haven't touched for a few months.

I am just trying to build the app using xCode and getting this error

[image]

I am running the app on my physical device

[image]

---

I have tried doing

```
Product -> Clean build folder
```

and

```
yarn cache clean --force
```

But the problem persists.

---

**Update**
I also keep receiving this error

```
Failed to find or create execution context for description '<IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x7f9a97966130> System content for IBCocoaTouchFramework-ThirteenAndLater <IBScaleFactorDeviceTypeDescription: 0x7f9a9565efe0> scaleFactor=2x'.
```

It went away when I

- cleaned my build folder
- removed my node_modules, Pods, Podfile.lock, and yarn.lock

But then it just came back

This is my launchscreen

[image]

Comment: did you eject this project?

Comment: @MuhammadNuman yes, but months ago and it worked after that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Solution 1:

```
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```

## Solution 2

When upgrading, you may drag around old simulators no longer available with your current version of Xcode. You can clean these by running this command in **Terminal**:

```
xcrun simctl delete unavailable
```

Quit **Xcode** first just for good measures. From the documentation:

> Delete a device or all unavailable devices.

## Solution 3:

Installing/Reinstalling Simulators worked!!

Look under (XCode Preferences-> Downloads -> Components)

## Solution 4 (Sam Solution)

just **delete Xcode** and install the newest version from developer.apple.com/download/more .

Comment: It didn't help, sorry. Even with a `clean build folder`

Comment: @Sam can you try solution 2 and 3?

Comment: Solution 2 didn't work. Maybe solution 3, but I don't think I have room on my computer for all the simulators. Now that you mention it though, I'm thinking I might have deleted something important in Xcode when I was trying to free up space on my computer

Comment: Solution 3 didn't work. How many simulators would i have to download? Also, I'm trying to run it on a real device

Comment: I ended up just deleting Xcode and installing the newest version from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ . You helped me figure out that the problem was with Xcode, so if you add this solution to your list of solutions I'll mark your answer correct

Comment: @Sam I have added your solution

Comment: @MuhammadNuman not working any solution. I am using Xcode 14.2 and installing the watchOS 9.1. Please help

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo xcrun simctl shutdown all && sudo xcrun simctl erase all
```

It helped to fix Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your simulator run times by deleting the contents of this folder: "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes" then restarting Xcode and the simulator and trying again.

Sometimes the data there can get old and needs to be rebuilt.

Comment: I don't even think I'm using a simulator, I'm trying to run on a real device

Answer (score 0):

There is no CoreSimulator folder inside Developer for me. Only one folder exists that of CommandLineTools. How to go forward with this because there is neither any simulator image displayed and executing directly the simulator app causes it to crash

[Please check from apple developer](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11706?sr=stream&ru=8243)